# Same height on 2 col list row CSS JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

How can I make a row with the same height using a col list? I'm working on a wordpress menu and this is how it looks now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvEXa.png

and this is what I need:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNOiW.png

I tried to do it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</a></li>
</ul>

ul{ 
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
} 
ul li{
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex; 
}
```

but it makes the same height on all list items and not only in the row I need.

Any idea how to make it? Thanks!

Comment: Post your HTML too please

Comment: Your code works as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/5n4car6t/ (although I would remove the float)

Comment: @Pete Flexbox ignores float in children elements either way. He/she CAN leave it if he negates flex using break points, If not, he/she SHOULD remove the float, in order to keep his CSS semantically correct.

Comment: @George just saying that it's not necessary - either way not bothered if they leave it or remove it - I know how flex works no need to SHOUT words at me - the main point of my above comment is that their code is working as they want it to

Comment: @Bryan I added the html it is a ul li list

Comment: With the code you posted the "long" li is on second position on the left column, but the height is correct. On your screenshots it is on third position but the height is not correct. Do you have different code used in your screenshot example?

Comment: @Pete mmm interesting... maybe there is something else wrong in my html/css I'm going to check again.

Comment: @sina_rosemann yes I'm trying different codes, in the screenshot it's a ul {    column-count: 2;} and ul li{display:inline-block}

Comment: ok understood. Well in that case your code works for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply use a table? that might be more appropriate here:

```
<div class="col-5">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem ipsum is simply dummy</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum is simply dummy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem ipsum is simply dummy</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum is simply dummy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;">lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum is simply dummy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem ipsum is simply dummy</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum is simply dummy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem ipsum is simply dummy</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum is simply dummy</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Disclaimer: I tend to use bootstrap on all my pages because I like the 12 column layout. you do not have to use Bootstrap to make this work though. Simply define the width of whatever div you place this table in.

Comment: I can't, it is a cms menu and it use a ul li structure

Comment: I see you may wish to update your question with this information to avoid further confusion.